# Why isn't AddMonths() working on my DateTime? (see code)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

Controller:

```
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

        ViewData["now"] = startDate.ToString();
        ViewData["interval"] = interval.ToString();

        startDate.AddMonths(interval);

        ViewData["later"] = startDate.ToString();
```

View:

```
Now: <%=ViewData["now"] %><br />

Later: <%=ViewData["later"] %><br />

Interval: <%=ViewData["interval"] %>
```

This yields:

```
Now: 10/2/2009 12:17:14 PM
Later: 10/2/2009 12:17:14 PM
Interval: 6
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
startDate  = startDate.AddMonths(interval);
```

Comment: This is correct.  Operations on DateTimes are non-destructive.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

This method does not change the value of this DateTime object. Instead, a new DateTime object is returned whose value is the result of this operation.

You really want:

ViewData["later"] = startDate.AddMonths(interval).ToString();

or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

[AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) returns a new DateTime with the value.

```
startDate = startDate.AddMonths(interval)
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to assign the result of the `AddMonths` to a variable. `AddMonths` does not change the value of the object it was called on, but rather returns a new `DateTime` with the value that results from the operation leaving the original `DateTime` value unchanged.